# draggable layouts from elements. like gridster.js

Tags: drag-and-drop, draggable, jquery-ui-draggable, dashboard, gridster

I would like to have a page with draggable elements. Something like this

[gridster demo](http://gridster.net/demos/dynamic-grid-width.html)

The only difference is that I would like the user to have the option not only to resize but to hide and show the elements as well. (something like a dashboard)

the closest I came to is this :
[angular dashboard](http://datatorrent.github.io/malhar-dashboard-webapp/#/) but sadly I don't want to use angular.js

I would like to see if you guys know of any libraries like that.

thanks